# Precompilled Tensorflow - Programmatic way to get the CUDA & CUDNN version it was built against

Tags: tensorflow, custom-operator

I am wondering if there is a programmatic way to find out against which CUDA and CUDNN version an installed tensorflow version was built?
For example, a compiled Tensorflow installation can return which CXX11_ABI_FLAG was used while it was built:
`python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.CXX11_ABI_FLAG)"` ->0

The background is the following:
I'm building Tensorflow OPs according to [adding an op with tensorflow binary installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#compile_the_op_using_your_system_compiler_tensorflow_binary_installation). This uses pre-compiled TF to retrieve the required include paths and compile flags, to make sure that Tensorflow and new Op are compatible. 
But since our systems have multiple CUDA & CUDNN versions, I also need to provide the path of the desired versions to the compiler. E.g. for  Cuda 8.0 the following flag  `-L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/` to specify its path.
But this also opens up an error path, as the Op can now be built successfully with a different CUDA/CUDNN version, which leads to errors during run-time way later.
So I want to create a safety check, to ensure that the CUDA/CUDNN paths lead to the same versions, as the ones Tensorflow was built against.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. How would a "programmatic way" of finding this information help you in a build process, which seems to be your goal? When or how would such a "programmatic way" be executed during  compilation?

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully better explain what I need.

Comment: Doesn't `ldd libtensorflow_framework.so` work for you?